# How to set the image into a desired size

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, image-resizing

I am using twitter bootstrap.

```
<img id="profileImage"
        data-src="holder.js/300x200" src="${picurls}">
```

Now the problem is when i upload a image the img area changes to the uploaded image size.
I want a fix image area and every image showld adjust within that box.

Answer (score -1):

There is something wrong in it, please try following block of code

Add line into your img tag.
style="width: 300px; height: 200px;

Answer (score -1):

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
  <li class="span4">
      <img id="profileImage" data-src="holder.js/300x200" src="${picurls}">
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Twitter bootstrap uses the 12 columns grid, so the span4 is telling that the image has 4/12 of the width of the page (or the container it's in).